# Find duplicate files in a specific sharepoint document library using powershell script

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to find the duplicate files in my "Test" library in SharePoint, using the below code

```
  [system.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
    function Get-DuplicateFiles ($RootSiteUrl)
    {
    $spsite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($RootSiteUrl)
    $Items = @()
    $Duplicates = @()
    $duplicateItems = @()
    $duplicateshelper = @()
    foreach ($SPweb in $spSite.allwebs)
    {
    Write-Host "Checking " $spWeb.Title " for duplicate documents"
    foreach ($list in $spWeb.Lists)
    {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $list.RootFolder.Url -notlike "_*" -and $list.RootFolder.Url -notlike "SitePages*")
    {
    foreach($item in $list.Items)
    {
    $record = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
    if($item.File.length -gt 0)
    {
      $record | Add-Member NoteProperty FileName ($item.file.Name)
      $record | Add-Member NoteProperty FullPath ($spWeb.Url + "/" + $item.Url)
      $Items += $record
    }
    }
    }
    }
    $spWeb.Dispose()
    $duplicateItems = $Items | Group-Object Filename| Where-Object {$_.Count -gt 1}
    foreach($dup in $duplicateItems)
    {
       foreach($item in $Items | Where-Object {$_.Filename -eq $dup.Name})
      {
        if ($duplicateshelper -notcontains $item.Fullpath) 
        {
           $duplicateshelper += $item.Fullpath
           $found  = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
           $found  | Add-Member NoteProperty Filename ($item.FileName)
           $found  | Add-Member NoteProperty Fullpath ($item.Fullpath)
           $duplicates += $found 
        }
      }
   }
  }
  return $duplicates  | Out-GridView
 }
  Get-DuplicateFiles("http://sp2010/Test")
```

this giving me result from all the document libraries(Test, SearchCenter, Pages, News) in the site, I want only from "Test" library. Please let me know where to change the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this `foreach` specifically at if condition

```
foreach ($list in $spWeb.Lists)
    {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $list.Title -eq "Test"
```

add this  `$list.Title -eq "Test"`

The full code should be like this

```
foreach ($list in $spWeb.Lists)
    {
    if($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" -and $list.RootFolder.Url -notlike "_*" -and $list.RootFolder.Url -notlike "SitePages*")
    {

if($item.Title -eq "Test")
{
    foreach($item in $list.Items)
    {
    $record = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
    if($item.File.length -gt 0)
    {
      $record | Add-Member NoteProperty FileName ($item.file.Name)
      $record | Add-Member NoteProperty FullPath ($spWeb.Url + "/" + $item.Url)
      $Items += $record
    }
}
    }
    }
    }
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: I am also here if you need any clarification or help

Comment: It's not giving any result when I added $list.Name -eq "Test" to the if condition.

Comment: should you send to me the if statement after your modification ?

Comment: Here it is : if($list.BaseType -eq “DocumentLibrary” -and $list.Name -eq "Test" -and $list.RootFolder.Url -notlike “_*” -and $list.RootFolder.Url -notlike “SitePages*”)

Comment: try to use Title instead of name

Comment: I updated the answer above $list.Title instead of $list.Name

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure of your list name, you should probably avoid enumerating manually all the available lists and just accessing the target list directly.

```
foreach ($SPweb in $spSite.allwebs)
{
   Write-Host "Checking " $spWeb.Title " for duplicate documents"

   $list = $spWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Your List Display Name")

   if(($list) -and ($list.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary"))
   {
      foreach($item in $list.Items)
      {
         $record = New-Object -TypeName System.Object
         if($item.File.length -gt 0)
         {
            $record | Add-Member NoteProperty FileName ($item.file.Name)
            $record | Add-Member NoteProperty FullPath ($spWeb.Url + "/" + $item.Url)
            $Items += $record
         }
      }
   }

   // your original code
   // .......
```

Just replace the `"Your List Display Name"` part with the actual name of your list - "Test" in your example. The rest of the code should be the same.